# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Test::__construct() must be callable, string given, called

Tags: php, typecasting-operator

Thank you for reading. Please help me understand why my callable argument is failing. My code is below:

```
class Test {

/** @var callable */
private $callable;

/** @var mixed[] */
private $args;

public function __construct(callable $callable, array $args)
{
    $this->callable = $callable;
    $this->args = $args;
}

public function testme() {
    if(is_callable($this->callable)) {
    return "yes";
    } else {
        call_user_func($this->callable);
    }
}
}

$test = new Test('testme', array('foo'=>'bar'));
```

the above code generates the following error:-
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Test::__construct() must be callable, string given, called

Comment: `$test = new Test('testme', array('foo'=>'bar');` in this what is `testme`? Is this function defined anywhere outside the class?

Comment: You're attempting to define a callback that refers to an instance method, but when you call the constructor the instance does not yet exist, so what you're trying to do here is impossible. [chicken/egg problem] You could pass the method name as a string and set `$this->callable = [$this, $callable];` in the constructor, but this is still gross and nonsensical. I think that if you provided more context about what you're actually going to do with code like this, rather than a strawman example, we might be able to provide better suggestions.

Comment: Not sure what about this error message is unclear. You've defined the method to require a `callable` but obviously the string "testme" is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Sammitch, but if you just want to pass some callable into any part of application you need to define this callable like this

```
class Test {

    /** @var callable */
    private $callable;

    public function __construct(callable $callable)
    {
        $this->callable = $callable;
    }

}


$someFunction = function () {
   //... some function body
};

new Test($someFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing with your code. First of all the callback should be called somewhere. As an example, I created a method `callMe()`.

```
<?php

class Test {
    
    /** @var callable */
    private $callable;
    
    /** @var mixed[] */
    private $args;
    
    public function __construct(callable $callable, array $args)
    {
        $this->callable = $callable;
        $this->args = $args;
    }
    
    /**
     * example for calling the callable given
     */
    function callMe() {
        call_user_func($this->callable);
    }
    
    public function testme() {
        print 'called method '.__METHOD__.PHP_EOL;
        print_r($this->args);
        
        if(is_callable($this->callable)) {
            print "yes";
        } else {
            call_user_func($this->callable);
        }

    }
}

/**
 * Test function outside the class Test
 */
function testme(){
    print 'called function '.__METHOD__.PHP_EOL;
}
```

## Test scenarios

```
$test = new Test('testme', array('foo'=>'bar1'));
$test2 = new Test([$test,'testme'], array('foo'=>'bar2'));
$test3 = new Test(['Test','testme'], array('foo'=>'bar3'));
```

### Scenario 1

```
$test->callMe();
```

Output:

```
called function testme
```

This means: The function `testme` outside the class gets called.

As you didn't define `testme` outside the class, you'll get the described error message. `testme` isn't callable in this case.

### Scenario 2

```
$test2->callMe();
```

Output:

```
called method Test::testme
Array
(
    [foo] => bar1
)
yes
```

The callback gets called. But function has the data of the first instance (from the first scenario). This happens, because the first instance is given into the callable: `[$test,'testme']`.

### Scenario 3

```
$test3->callMe();
```

Output:

```
called method Test::testme
Array
(
    [foo] => bar3
)
yes
```

This calls the callback from the current object. But be careful: This only seems to work, if you call it via `call_user_func`. Calling it like the following code will call the method statically.

```
function callMe() {
    $callable = $this->callable;
    $callable();
}
```

Statically means: outside the object context. So, `$this` wouldn't be available inside this method.

Comment: how does this work ? always get 'must be callable, string given' error when passing a string to a callable type parameter. dont get this code to work with php 7+.

Comment: Then the function, you want to call does not exists (Testet with PHP 7.4):

`function test(callable $test){
 print $test();
}
function fooBar(){
 return __METHOD__.' called';
}

test('fooBar');
/*fooBar called*/

test('foo');
/*Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to test() must be callable, string given*/
`

Comment: thanks, my environment is causing the problem - dont know why but it doesnt work in our project - tested the same code on phpsandbox and it works :/ sry for the confusion